# Should I use append line or +=

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

When adding text to a string should I use :

```
var myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); 
myStringBuilder.AppendLine("some text");
```

or

```
var myString = "";
myString += ("some text");
```

and why ?

Comment: In fairness, that is definitely not a duplicate question - it focuses on why `StringBuilder` is faster than separate string concatenations, not on this specific question on why the alternative syntax also works *on StringBuilder* and whether the two are functionally identical. Also, there's some stuff in that other topic that isn't entirely true. In a well-prepared case multiple concatenations will never outperform `StringBuilder`, if you select it's initial capacity correctly with the [alternative constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1h0a5sy.aspx).

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Do you mean `myString.Append()` instead of `AppendLine` which would presumably give a different result when compared to `+=` due to `AppendLine` calling `Environment.NewLine` internally, or have I missed something?

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to append several lines `StringBuilder.AppendLine` would be better performance-wise. If it's just one then use `+=`.

`+=` will create a brand new, immutable, `string` each time you call it. `StringBuilder` uses an expanding buffer internally then when you want to use a string call `StringBuilder.ToString()`

Comment: This assumes that the implementation of operator + for StringBuilder is the same as for string. Why would that be the case? It could very easily internally call Append.

Comment: There is no += in `StringBuilder`. I believe the question may be causing some confusion. The `string` class has a `+=` operator.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use `AppendLine` and its brethren functions. The second syntax works, but only because there are enough implicit conversions available. Even for a single append it will be less performant than the `Append` variant since it does some extra string allocations internally to do the append, while the `StringBuilder` already has space reserved internally. I wouldn't be surprised if a representative benchmark showed the first example to be at least 3 times faster than the second one, for a single append.